# How to show a button on screen touch, while keeping the swipe?

Tags: java, android, swipe-gesture

I have an activity with some images and I'm using swipe to load the next image. I need when I touch the image to show a button, for image saving. How can I do that? Here's my code:

```
public class Photo_gallery extends Activity{


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.photo_gallery);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private int[] mImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.p1,
            R.drawable.p2,
            R.drawable.p3,
            R.drawable.p4,
          .
          .
          .
            R.drawable.p108
        };


        public int getCount() {
          return mImages.length;
        }


        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }


        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
          Context context = Photo_gallery.this;
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
          int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
              R.dimen.padding_medium);
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
          imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
          return imageView;
        }


        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
      }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

EDIT:

My XML code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/view_pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to show a button on the screen when you click the image, you can put a button in your layout with the parameter `android:visibility="gone"`.

Then, when the user clicks the image (just put an `OnClickListener()` for the ImageView), call `button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to show the button. Then when the user performs any other action and you want to hide the button again, call `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: I'm using ViewPager so I can't add a button. I don't use imageView

Comment: Right, sorry a ViewPager. Still the same logic should apply. You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.photo_gallery);`. Any reason you can't add a button to that layout?

Comment: I tried but I can't. I've edited my first post to add my XML code.